# Not able to view the save record current record id lightning datatale and lightning-record-edit-form in lwc

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, salesforce-id, lwc-wire-adapter, record

used lightning record edit form and datatable ,I need to save current record data with the current record id but am getting all pervious record data in table.there is any solution.
In this picture, I save only one record with the current record id but am getting all previous record data.

I don't know how to stop the previous record on the table. can anyone help
[image]

If I add  WHERE CLAUS I unable to view the record and unable to save the record

### Apex:

```
 @AuraEnabled(Cacheable = true)
public static List<Bank_Account__c> getId(Id id){
    return [SELECT
                  Name,Account__c,    Account_Number__c,Account_Type__c,Balance__c,
                      Client__c,Sort_Code__c,    Sum_of_Credits__c,Sum_of_Debits__c
             FROM Bank_Account__c
             WHERE Client__c=:id
            ];
}
```

### Js:

```
@api recordId;

@wire(getId)

contacts(result){ 

    this.refreshTable = result;

    if (result.data) {
        this.data = result.data;
        this.error = undefined;

    } else if (result.error) {
        this.error = result.error;
        this.data = undefined;
    }

} 
  handleSubmit(event) {

 // this.Bank();
  this.isTrue = true;
    // prevending default type sumbit of record edit form
   
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.detail.fields.recordId);

    // querying the record edit form and submiting fields to form
    this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(event.detail.fields);
           console.log('onsubmit: '+ event.detail.id);


    // closing modal
    this.recordFound = true;
    this.isModalOpen= false
     
     
        // Show success messsage
        this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Success!!',
        message: event.detail.fields.FirstName + ' '+ event.detail.fields.LastName +' Contact updated Successfully!!.',
        variant: 'success'
        }),);
 
     


}

handleSuccess() {

    //this.Bank();

     this.isTrue = true;
    return refreshApex(this.refreshTable);
}
```

Comment: You're querying every record in the database (there is no WHERE condition), so of course you'll get every record in the database. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My requirement is when I insert and save the record I need to show only the current record on the current page. I need to avoid the previous record not to show on table

Comment: Do not delete and repost questions. This is not an acceptable way to draw attention on Salesforce Stack Exchange.

Comment: I did'not getting any attention toward the question so only I repost

Comment: Yes, I understand exactly what you did. I am telling you, @meenu, that that behavior is not acceptable on this site. Don't do it again.

Comment: If you wish to find a high quality answer, please review [ask] and then [edit] your question to provide a clearer explanation of exactly what you are trying to do and the problem you're encountering. Right now, this implementation doesn't really make sense.

Comment: **Please [edit] your post to clarify.** Please do not post comments to add information.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `bankId` is set correctly to the `recordId`, then if you want to *only* query for that record, you need to add a WHERE clause to your query:

```java
@AuraEnabled(Cacheable = true)
public static List<Bank_Account__c> getId(Id bankId){
    return [
        SELECT Id
            ,Name
            ,Account_Type__c
            ,Sort_Code__c
            ,Account_Number__c
        FROM Bank_Account__c
        WHERE Id = :bankId
    ];
}
```

**Edit**

> I have one doubt Apex Bank Account is lookup with contact and Bank related tab is present in the Contact page so how I can take a record Id of contact with Bank Object

If you need to query for the `Bank_Account__c` and `recordId` is a `Contact` record, then you follow the same process but your WHERE clause is going to use the lookup field on the Bank Account. Whatever that field may be.

```sql
        SELECT Id
            ,Name
            ,Account_Type__c
            ,Sort_Code__c
            ,Account_Number__c
        FROM Bank_Account__c
        WHERE Contact__c = :myContactId
```

Comment: I have one doubt Apex Bank Account is lookup with contact and Bank related tab is present in the Contact page so how I  can take a record Id  of contact with Bank Object

Comment: @meenu see my edit above. You'll need to query using the lookup field.

Comment: how I can check this query in test query at developer console if i check throws an error "unknow error passing"

Comment: You cannot use variables in the Query Editor, if that's what you're doing. You will need to put the ID in as a text literal: `WHERE Contact__c = '50130000000014c'`

Comment: How to get record ID of parent object (Contact__c) and child object (Relationship [custom object Name (Bank_Account__c)])?A Contact__c is the parent of a custom object in our org (Relationship) with Contact__c.the same filed name is contact__c in Bank_Account__c object. @nbrown

Comment: you know how to resolve off it @nbrown

Comment: These are all custom objects @meenu, I can't speak to how you have the data model set up. If there really _is_ a master-detail relationship, then a `Bank_Account__c` cannot exist without its master record. If it's a lookup though it might be possible to create a Bank Account without a Contact. Use the Schema Builder to get a sense for how your objects relate to one another.

Comment: It is lookup relationship contatc__c is a standard object and Child Relationship Name with Bank_Account__c @nbrown